# Как получить текущую погоду на русском через api?

Tags: api

Получаю текущую погоду в российских городах через api openweathermap.org .
Но он дает результат на английском, чтобы получить результат на русском передаю параметр lang=ru, но все равно результат на английском языке.

Получаю по данные по почтовому индексу 610000 это Киров.
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=610000&lang=ru&appid=b1b35bba8b434a28a0be2a3e1071ae5b&units=imperial

В api указано, что можно передавать параметры языка lang=ru , но в примере они применяют к получению прогнозов.

Так как получить данные на русском?

Comment: Пишет, что пасмурно на русском. Видимо, это всё, что они локализовали?

Comment: Не подходит pogoda.com/api там только прогнозы погоды. текущую погоду не отдает

Comment: Если поиграться с другими языками (de, fr, it) и другими индексами, то ``Main`` всегда будет на английском, а ``description`` на выбранном языке. Так что нужно использовать ``description``, а ``Main`` у них просто ключ, похоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный сервис не предоставляет данные на русском в полном объеме. Смотрите в сторону [Яндекс.Погода API](http://tech.yandex.ru%E2%80%BAAPI%20%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81.%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B) или [api.pogoda.ru](http://api.pogoda.ru).

Comment: Яндекс Погода уже неделю высылает ключ к своему апи

Comment: Апи gismeteo не работает. Точнее у них оказывается платный api

Comment: @md5hash api.pogoda.ru

Comment: api.pogoda.ru ссылка недоступна. у них же нет апи

Comment: @md5hash, так здесь: https://www.pogoda.com/api.

Comment: спасибо попробую pogoda.com/api

Answer (score 1):

Я у себя сделал так: в скрипте **~/.harmattan-assets/get_weathe** последнюю строчку изменил на:

```
curl -s "${api_prefix}weather?${appid}${id}${units}&lang=ru" -o "$weather"
```

То есть, напрямую указал локаль = `ru`, причем именно `ru` а не `ru_RU`.

Тогда в **weather.json** появляется:

> {"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"пасмурно","icon":"04d"}

Дальше в **.conkyrc** изменил в строке запроса облачности с `main` на `description`.

Всё теперь на русском.

Comment: Сейчас буду думать как hPa изменить на мм.рт.ст